# Monogame 2D lighting

Tags: c#, monogame, hlsl, effects, lighting

I've been trying to implement some very basic lighting in Monogame following several tutorials I found online (namely, here):

http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/apis-and-tools/2d-lighting-system-in-monogame-r4131

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40563/how-can-i-acheive-a-smooth-2d-lighting-effect

I have tried to copy their approach, but have been unsuccessful and was hoping someone would be able to tell me why.

I load a light mask texture (the same one as in the first link), a simple object to test the lighting and my Effect file (these have been declared further up the class):

```
lightMask = ScreenManager.Instance.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites\\Effects\\LightMask");
cursor = ScreenManager.Instance.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites\\UI\\Cursor");
effect = ScreenManager.Instance.Content.Load<Effect>("Effects\\LightEffect");
```

I initialise them here:

```
GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice = ScreenManager.Instance.GraphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice;
var pp = graphicsDevice.PresentationParameters;
lightsTarget = new RenderTarget2D(graphicsDevice, pp.BackBufferWidth, pp.BackBufferHeight);
mainTarget = new RenderTarget2D(graphicsDevice, pp.BackBufferWidth, pp.BackBufferHeight);
```

and draw everything here:

```
GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice = ScreenManager.Instance.GraphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice;

graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(lightsTarget);
graphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Additive);
spriteBatch.Draw(lightMask, ScreenCentre - new Vector2(128), Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();

graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(mainTarget);
graphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(cursor, ScreenCentre - new Vector2(64), Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();

graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
graphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

effect.Parameters["LightMask"].SetValue(lightsTarget);
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
spriteBatch.Draw(mainTarget, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

(the -new Vector2(128) and -new Vector(64) are just to centre the sprites in the middle of the screen).

Here is my Effect file:

```
#if OPENGL
#define SV_POSITION POSITION
#define VS_SHADERMODEL vs_3_0
#define PS_SHADERMODEL ps_3_0
#else
#define VS_SHADERMODEL vs_4_0_level_9_1
#define PS_SHADERMODEL ps_4_0_level_9_1
#endif

sampler2D TextureSampler : register(s0);

Texture2D LightMask;
sampler2D LightMaskSampler = sampler_state { Texture = <LightMask>; };

float4 MainPS(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR0, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
  float4 lightColour = tex2D(LightMaskSampler, texCoord);
  float4 tex = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord);

  return lightColour * tex;
}

technique SpriteDrawing
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_5_0 MainPS();
    }
};
```

The code is a little scrappy, because I just wanted to get this working.  As far as I can tell I have set everything up correctly, but all I see is a black screen.

When I draw each render state separately without the Effect, I do see each texture in the correct place, so it seems my shader is not combining them together correctly.

Any light that can be shed on the matter (cheap joke) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick check: when you wrote you "light mask texture (the same one as in the first link)", did you actually download `lightmask.png` from that page, or created/downloaded a semitransparent white mask? Because the article author wrote the one that he used in the demo is a white transparent gradient, and this has a black layer to be visible against his white website background.

Comment: I tried to run this (with the [correct white+alpha texture](http://i.imgur.com/eEaaJWK.png)), and it worked. But you won't see much of anything if your `mainTarget` is completely black, because the shader only affects the alpha channel (given the correct texture). Try clearing your `mainTarget` with `graphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Green);` or something like that and see what happens.